# PHP - How can we display generated numbers for related rows if using class function

Tags: php, mysql, auto-generate

How can i generate a numbers to the table that has been fetch a data from database, here are my situation:

//Action File Calling a data

```
$loads = array();
$loadno = $_GET['eig'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_load WHERE load_no='$loadno' ORDER BY inv ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $loads[] = new VerifyLoads($row);
}
        foreach($loads as $c){
             echo $c->markup_print();
        }
```

// Class file receive request

```
    public function markup_print()
    {
    $d = &$this->data;

    return '
        <tr id="line-'.$d['id'].'">
            <td class="iprint">'.GENERATE_NUMBER_HERE.'</td>
            <td class="cprint">'.$d['customer_name'].'</td>
            <td class="cprint">'.$d['inv'].'</td>
            <td class="rprint">'.$d['value'].'</td>
            <td class="cprint">'.$d['ctn'].'</td>
            <td class="iprint"></td>
            <td class="iprint"></td>
            <td class="iprint"></td>
        </tr>       
        ';
    }
```

Comment: Generate what kind of number?

Comment: Note this is vulnerable to SQL injection. At a minimum, you _must_ call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$loadno`.  `$loadno = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['eig'])`

Comment: tq for your concern..i just want to generate line of numbers, thank u for your guide in prevent SQL injection!Nice dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am fairly unsure as to what *kind* of number you're looking to generate, based on your output I'm assuming you want a simple line-number for the current record that's being displayed. The difficulty, in this case, is because each line is a separate instance of the `VerifyLoads` class.

To handle this you could take one of several ways. The quickest and easiest method will work because you display them in the order you created them. This method will involve two new variables in the `VerifyLoads` class; the first is a static variable to keep the total-line count and the second is a non-static variable to keep the current instance's count:

```
class VerifyLoads {
    private $_lineTotal = 1;
    private $_lineNumber = -1;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_lineNumber = self::$_lineTotal++;
    }

    public function markup_print() {
        $d = &$this->data;

        return '
            <tr id="line-'.$d['id'].'">
            <td class="iprint">'.$this->_lineNumber.'</td>
            <td class="cprint">'.$d['customer_name'].'</td>
            <td class="cprint">'.$d['inv'].'</td>
            <td class="rprint">'.$d['value'].'</td>
            <td class="cprint">'.$d['ctn'].'</td>
            <td class="iprint"></td>
            <td class="iprint"></td>
            <td class="iprint"></td>
            </tr>       
        ';
    }
}
```

An alternative method, if you didn't display the records in the same order you created them would be to also keep a static variable in the class but to have a local method that returned the current line:

```
class VerifyLoads {
    private static $_lineNumber = 1;

    private function _currentLine() {
        return self::$_lineNumber++;
    }

    // .. code as normal ..
    // .. to access, just call $this->_currentLine()
}
```

If you need to use the second method and also use it to display multiple tables on the same page you could implement a `resetLineNumber()` method to set the static variable back to `1` as well.

On the flip-side, I may have completely misunderstood your question. If this is the case, please elaborate as-to-what kind of number you need displayed and I'll revise.

Comment: that is what i find for...tq i will try soon!